# Inserting a filter between Avi Muxer and File Writer?

Tags: video, directshow, avi, video-recording

Is it possible to insert a filter between Avi Mux filter and the file writer filter. 
The graph builder inserts and auto connects both filters by calling ICaptureGraphBuilder2::SetOutputFileName. Since the interface of the file writer is from type IFileSinkFilter (not derived from IBaseFilter) this interface does not expose any function like Disconnect or Connect or to enumerate the filter pins. Hence I find no way to insert a filter between these both filters.
Was this intentionally of MS to have both filters as a kind of an atomic construct? Or is there any other way to manage this.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert a filter there but as you noticed it needs to be a different filter. Specifically, [File Writer Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/DirectShow/file-writer-filter)'s input pin implements `IStream` interface. This is what [AVI Mux Filter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/DirectShow/avi-mux-filter) also expects.

If you provide a compatible filter, you can connect through it.

Comment: At least the sample grabber filter will not work as an intermediate filter. Seems I have to write an own compatible filter.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft file writer filter does expose an IBaseFilter interface as well as IFileSinkFilter (and probably other interfaces too). You just need to use QueryInterface to get that interface (rather than IFileSinkFilter inheriting from IBaseFilter).

```
IFileSinkFilter *pFileSink;
IBaseFilter* filter = NULL;
hr = pFileSink->QueryInterface( IID_IBaseFilter, (void **)&filter );
```

If this is unclear make sure you have a good basic understanding of [COM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/com/iunknown-and-interface-inheritance) as this is used throughout DirectShow. Also refer to the [Microsoft DirectShow documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375454(v=vs.85).aspx) which is well written and definitive:

If you happen to be working in C# rather than C++ then if I recall correctly you can cast between different C# COM wrapper objects to automatically QueryInterface for the corresponding interface and the result is null if the QueryInterface fails (not really my area of expertise).

In one of your comments you mentioned the sample grabber. If you're trying to grab frames of audio or video, you would need to put the sample grabber *before* the input pins of the avi mux filter.

The mediatype stream connection between AVI mux and file writer is really just a way of sending simple I/O commands over a pin connection to write/read an byte stream (it's the AVI mux's job to work out the formatting). These IStream calls or samples will not always correspond to individual frames of audio or video.

The [GraphStudioNext](https://github.com/cplussharp/graph-studio-next) file write analyzer filter will show you the individual samples and IStream calls.

Comment: I think I know how to deal with the QueryInterface methods so far. And your seceond last paragraph confirms my assumption that the pin connection between avi muxer and file writer is not a connection like the others and it is not possible to place a filter between both filters.